# Prevent window from redrawing

Tags: gtk, pygtk

is it possible to prevent automatic redrawing of window? I want it to redraw only when I issue queue_draw().

**Explanation:**
I need this because I'm using a 3rd party commercial library for industrial graphics which I can tell when to redraw, but also it redraws when X tells it to and it is not possible to prevent that. Therefore, I need to prevent that because of an app-specific requirements and make it redraw only when *I* tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what's the point? If you don't make it redraw automatically, you'll be unable to minimize/maximize the window, move it from the background to the foreground... And if these are actions that never happen, then your windows is already redrawn only when you call queue_draw. Just add some trace code in the `expose-event` handler, and you'll see it.

So I think your're looking to at the wrong solution for the wrong problem.

Edit:
so what you need may be the [GTK_APP_PAINTABLE](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/chap-drawing-model.html#app-paintable-widgets) flag.

Comment: I didn't ask whether other people find my course of action sensible, I asked if it is possible to prevent it from redrawing. I needed this for non-general-user usage, strictly for some in-house testing.